# Does Barret know about Cloud's disguise?

Tags: final-fantasy

So, in the 1997 game, Final Fantasy 7 there's an incident which is highly embarrassing for the game's super-macho protagonist, Cloud.

> Cloud dresses as a woman (specifically a prostitute) to infiltrate the home of Don Corneo, a gang boss, and rescue Tifa, who he knows has entered the home.

Barret would probably find this incident highly amusing and make fun of Cloud for it, only we don't see him caught up on events because

> he is busy trying to prevent a section of the Midgar plate from being detached, crushing a section of the city's slums.

Is there any confirmation in-universe that Barret is either aware of it, or that it passed him by?